# Is modifying an academic transcript illegal?

Tags: united-states, fraud, academia

On my University of Washington unofficial transcript, it says

> ANY ALTERATION OR MODIFICATION OF THIS RECORD OR ANY COPY THEREOF MAY CONSTITUTE A FELONY AND/OR LEAD TO STUDENT DISCIPLINARY SANCTIONS.

Finding the bit about "student disciplinary sanctions" was quite easy. Finding the bit about "felony" is quite hard.

What "felony" - if any - is this referring to? The closest I've read about are articles relating to fraud. Is that what this is referencing to? I'm starting to believe this is just a scare tactic.

I'm narrowing this question down to exclude scenarios (and scenarios similar to) where you're hired somewhere because of falsified transcripts and cause the company damage. I'm looking for a federal law that specifically prohibits transcript modification and only that.

Comment: Why are you restricting your attention to *federal* laws? Washington State's forgery statute makes it a felony to "falsely make, complete, or alter a written instrument" with intent to injure or defraud.  http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.60.020

Comment: Until your comment, I was under the impression felonies equate to federal crimes. Clearly, I was wrong.

Comment: **Please do not use code block for something which is not actual code.** It causes difficulty for certain groups of users and interferes with accessibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This refers to state law (not federal law) [RCW 9A.60.070](http://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=9A.60.070), titled "False academic credentials". It is against the law to issue a false academic credential, and also to use a false academic credential. Getting to the penalty part, issuing a false academic credential is a class C felony, but knowingly using a false academic credential is only a gross misdemeanor. A false academic credential is

> a document that provides evidence or demonstrates completion of an
>   academic or professional course of instruction beyond the secondary
>   level that results in the attainment of an academic certificate,
>   degree, or rank, and that is not issued by a person or entity that:
>   (i) Is an entity accredited by an agency recognized as such by rule of
>   the student achievement council or has the international equivalents
>   of such accreditation; or (ii) is an entity authorized as a
>   degree-granting institution by the student achievement council; or
>   (iii) is an entity exempt from the requirements of authorization as a
>   degree-granting institution by the student achievement council; or
>   (iv) is an entity that has been granted a waiver by the student
>   achievement council from the requirements of authorization by the
>   council. Such documents include, but are not limited to, academic
>   certificates, degrees, coursework, degree credits, transcripts, or
>   certification of completion of a degree.

It then depends on the way in which you modify the transcript. One thing you could do is add text indicating that you received a BA degree, when in fact you did not receive any degree: this would be a false academic credential. If you want to go all the way for a felony charge, you have to *issue* and not just *use* a false academic credential. To *issue* a false credential, you have to do one of the following things:

> (a) Grants or awards a false academic credential or offers to grant or
>   award a false academic credential in violation of this section; (b)
>   Represents that a credit earned or granted by the person in violation
>   of this section can be applied toward a credential offered by another
>   person; (c) Grants or offers to grant a credit for which a
>   representation as described in (b) of this subsection is made; or (d)
>   Solicits another person to seek a credential or to earn a credit the
>   person knows is offered in violation of this section.

whereas the misdemeanor of *using* a false credential is (paraphrasing para 2)
falsely using or claiming to have a credential issued by an accredited institution for certain purposes. Those purposes include advertisement of a business, or with the intent to get a job, license, promotion, admission to educational program, or getting a government position.

However, there is also a law against [forgery](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.60.020), which is if a person

> with intent to injure or defraud: (a) He or she falsely makes,
>   completes, or alters a written instrument or; (b) He or she possesses,
>   utters, offers, disposes of, or puts off as true a written instrument
>   which he or she knows to be forged.

A forged instrument is [defined](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=9A.60.010) as "a written instrument which has been falsely made, completed, or altered", and a "written instrument" is

> (a) Any paper, document, or other instrument containing written or
>   printed matter or its equivalent; or (b) any access device, token,
>   stamp, seal, badge, trademark, or other evidence or symbol of value,
>   right, privilege, or identification.

and forgery is a class C felony. You can be charged with both crimes.